# Direction of limits on multiple integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to resolve a contradiction that I am facing while simplifying a double integral. I have a continuous function $v(x,y)$ over the square domain $[\pi,2\pi] \times [0,\pi]$. Alice simplifies it via a direct change of variables $ x = \pi + \theta, y = \pi-\phi$ to get $$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} v(x,y)dy dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{\pi}^{0} v(\pi + \theta, \pi-\phi) \text{Abs}(|J|)d\phi d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{\pi}^{0} v(\pi + \theta, \pi-\phi)d\phi d\theta$$
Bob simplifies the inner integral first by change of variables $y = \pi-\phi (dy = -d\phi)$  and then the outer integral by $x = \pi + \theta (dx = d\theta)$.
$$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} v(x,y) dydx = \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} v(\pi + \theta, \pi-\phi) d\phi d\theta.$$
Is Alice correct or Bob ? How does one determine the direction of the integral when changing variables in double and triple integration ?

Comment: Why isn't Alice integrating explicitly over a region? What's with the inner and outer integrals?

Comment: The region they are integrating over is $[\pi, 2\pi] \times [0,\pi]$. I was doing a change of variables to convert the region to $[0,\pi]^2$ and then use some properties of the function $v$ to simplify the integral. I realized that there are two ways for this simplification. I am not sure which one is right.

Comment: My question is why Alice wrote $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi}$ instead of $\iint_{[\pi, 2\pi] \times [0,\pi]}$ to define the original region of integration. This transforms to $\iint_{[0,\pi] \times [0,\pi]}$ without reversing the "direction" of integration (because there is no direction of integration). Alice clearly gets the wrong answer (try $v(x,y)=1$ and see). To put it another way: explain why Alice should take the absolute value of the determinant of the Jacobian and not just use the signed determinant.

Comment: Hold on, isn't $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} = \int_{[\pi,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]}$ ? This is what alice did: When $y=0$, $\phi = \pi$ and when $y = \pi$, $\phi = 0$, therefore $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} = \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{\pi}^{0}$.

Comment: Isn't direction necessary in integration? For instance, how do we integrate $\int_{[\pi,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]}1 ?$ I write it in the form $ \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} 1$. If direction is unecessary, then $\int_{[\pi,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]} = \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} = \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \int_{\pi}^{0}$.

Comment: No, $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi}$ is not the same as $\int_{[\pi,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]}$ at all. The first "integral" is really an integral of integrals that all have a direction. The second integral is really just one integral and has no direction. Think of how you would compute the mass of a thin plate knowing its density, which is non-negative everywhere. That's the second kind of integral. You can't get negative mass by integrating the density differently.

Comment: I see. Then, the results given on this webpage : https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/IteratedIntegrals.aspx , are they incorrect? They directly write integrals over rectangular regions as double integrals.

Comment: The link is correct. The iterated integrals are conceptually different from the double integral, but for a nice integrand (such as continuous one, etc.) they give the same value. That is what the equality in Fubini’s Theorem means.

Comment: Also, if we write $(x,y)=\Phi(\theta,\phi)=(\pi+\theta,\pi-\phi)$ and $D=[\pi,2\pi]\times[0,\pi]$, then the change of variables formula asserts that $$\int_{D}v(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int_{\Phi^{-1}(D)}v(\Phi(\theta,\phi))\,\left|J(\Phi)\right|\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi.$$ Note that both the region $D$ and the differential $\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ transforms without changing "orientation" (≈sign).

Comment: There is also a version that actually conforms to the orientation of the change of variable map. So, the change of variable formula will remain valid once you either keep or change the orientation of both the region and Jacobian simultaneously. (Alice did a mistake by changing the orientation for the region but keeping that for the Jacobian. She should not have mixed the two versions!) However this is usually swept under the rug in preliminary calculus because they require the notion of oriented line/surface/volume/manifold and it may confuse students.

Comment: @SangchulLee I started writing an answer a while ago but had to take a break to do the work I get paid for. In the meantime I saw you added several good comments. In particular, I think we agree about Alice's mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you cite [Paul's Online Notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/IteratedIntegrals.aspx), which is an excellent resource. (It's one of my favorite sources of information on calculus.)

I agree with everything written on the linked page. The error, I think, comes from neglecting the precise definitions and forms of what is written there.

Since the reasoning behind the question was explained only in comments at the time I wrote this, and comments are considered ephemeral, I am copying comments in order to flesh out this answer.

> Hold on, isn't $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} = \int_{[\pi,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]}$ ?

The two integrals have the **same value** if the rest of the notation is supplied correctly according to the general forms of the rectangular integrals on
[the page you cited](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/IteratedIntegrals.aspx),

$$
\iint\limits_{[\pi,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]} v(x,y)\,\mathrm dA
= \int_\pi^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi v(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.
$$

But you cannot just willy-nilly apply any method that people use on the integral on one side of this equation to the integral on the other side of this equation, because while the two sides are numerically equal, they are not the same kind of integral.
The integral on the left is a [double integral](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DoubleIntegrals.aspx), which by definition is

$$
\iint\limits_{[\pi,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]} v\left( {x,y} \right)\,\mathrm dA
 =  \lim_{n,\,m \to \infty } \sum_{i = 1}^n {\sum_{j = 1}^m {v\left( x_i^*,y_j^* \right)\,\Delta A} }, \tag1
$$

(where the sum on the right for each $n,m$ is taken by dividing the rectangle into a uniform $n\times m$ grid of rectangles each of area $\Delta A$),
whereas the integral on the right is an iterated integral,

$$
\int_\pi^{2\pi} \left[ \int_0^\pi v(x,y)\,\mathrm dy \right]\mathrm dx.
$$

The iterated integral is quite literally a definite integral of a single-parameter function $f(x)$ defined by

$$
f(x) = \int_0^\pi v(x,y)\,\mathrm dy
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^n v\left(x,y_i^*\right)\,\Delta y.\tag2
$$

> Isn't direction necessary in integration? For instance, how do we integrate $\int_{[\pi,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]} 1$? I write it in the form $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} 1$.

A direction of integration is implied by the usual notations for single-variable calculus, and it affects the sign of the result.
For example, in Equation $(2)$ above, $\Delta y$ is positive because
$$\Delta y = \frac1n(\pi - 0) = \frac\pi n.$$
But if you integrate $\displaystyle\int_\pi^0 v(x,y)\,\mathrm dy$ instead,
you will have $$\Delta y = \frac1n(0 - \pi) = -\frac\pi n,$$
which is a negative number. That's why we say

$$
\int_\pi^0 v(x,y)\,\mathrm dy = - \int_0^\pi v(x,y)\,\mathrm dy.
$$

In that sense, the $\mathrm dy$ in the integral denotes *signed distance,*
which is positive or negative depending on which direction you go when traveling from one end of a real interval to the other,
and not just *distance,* which is necessarily positive.
But when we write $\mathrm dA$ in a double integral,
it refers to area, which is always positive.
There is no way (within this definition of a double integral)
to integrate the double integral "backward" over the rectangle
$[\pi,2\pi]\times [0,\pi].$

As an aside, it **is** possible to define a surface integral in an oriented way. It can certainly be done with differential forms.
I'm not saying that integration over a region **must** be unoriented,
merely that the particular kind of integration defined in this part of
Paul's Online Notes.

The fact that one integral is oriented and the other is not
makes a difference in how we make a change of variables.
Note that when Bob made the substitution $y = \pi-\phi,$
he also wrote $dy = -d\phi.$
This is because in [the substitution rule of single-variable calculus](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/SubstitutionRuleIndefinite.aspx)
we view $y$ as a function of $\phi,$
$y = g(\phi),$ and we write
$$
\int f(y)\,\mathrm dy
= \int f(g(\phi))\,g'(\phi)\,\mathrm d\phi
= -\int f(g(\phi))\,\mathrm d\phi
$$
since $g'(\phi) = -1.$

In particular, note that we really care about the sign of the derivative
$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm d\phi}.$
This is due to the fact that orientation matters in this kind of integral.

When we do a [change of variables for a double integral](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx),
instead of the derivative $g'$ we have the Jacobian of the transformation.
Like the derivative $g',$ the Jacobian is signed.
But unlike in single-variable substitution,
we don't just multiply by the Jacobian when we change variables;
we multiply by the **absolute value** of the Jacobian.

The reason for the absolute value is that the double integral is unoriented,
whereas the sign of the Jacobian has to do with the orientation of the transformed region versus the orientation of the original region.
Since the double integral does not consider orientation,
it is an error to make that additional sign change when changing variables.
The absolute value prevents this error.

Alice's mistake is using the **absolute value** of the Jacobian
(which is a technique for the unoriented double integral)
in an iterated integral, which is oriented.

We can check the result by letting $v(x,y) = 1$ everywhere.
Using the definition of a double integral on a rectangle as shown in
Equation $(1),$ we find that

$$
\iint\limits_{[\pi,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]} 1\,\mathrm dA
 =  \lim_{n,\,m \to \infty } \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^m \Delta A.
$$

The right-hand side is a computation of the area of the rectangle,
which is $\pi^2,$ so that is the correct value of the integral.

On the other hand,
$$
\int_0^\pi \int_\pi^0 1\,\mathrm d\phi\,\mathrm d\theta
= \int_0^\pi [0 - \pi] \,\mathrm d\theta = - \pi^2.
$$
So we see by example that Alice has made a sign error.

A double integral is usually not this easy to solve directly,
so we often convert double integrals into iterated integrals
in order to evaluate them. But keep these guidelines in mind:

- After you convert the double integral to an iterated integral, any change of variables must use the change of variables formula from single-variable calculus. You cannot convert both variables simultaneously using the absolute value of the Jacobian.
- If you want to use the absolute value of the Jacobian to do a change of variables, do it **before** you convert the double integral to an iterated integral. You can then convert the double integral over the new region into an iterated integral.

Bob used the first method correctly. Alice could have used the second method correctly as follows:

$$
\iint\limits_{[\pi,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]} v(x,y)\,\mathrm dA
= \iint\limits_{[0,\pi]\times [0,\pi]} v(\pi + \theta, \pi-\phi)
\,\lvert J\rvert \,\mathrm dA
= \int_0^\pi \int_0^\pi v(\pi + \theta, \pi-\phi)
   \,\mathrm d\phi\,\mathrm d\theta.
$$

Even this is a little shaky notationally because you have to understand that we evaluate $v$ by letting the variables $x$ and $y$ have domains $[\pi,2\pi]$ and $[0,\pi]$ respectively in the first integral, but in the second integral we let the variables be $\theta$ and $\phi$, each with domain $[0,\pi].$
Some people would write $\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$ and
$\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\phi$ instead of $\mathrm dA$
in order to clarify this point,
although in my opinion this looks a bit too much like an iterated integral.
Also note that $\lvert J\rvert$ is the absolute value of the Jacobian, $J,$
and it is not necessary to take the absolute value twice.

Comment: Thank you David, this was very helpful.

Comment: In double integrals where we don't care about the orientation, how would we choose the limits of integration?

Comment: @user599310 The double integrals in the answer don't care about orientation and have limits expressed as regions, such as $[\pi,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]$. Do you mean how would you convert such an integral to an iterated integral? There's an example of that too: just make sure you integrate in the "positive" direction so you don't flip the sign of the integral.

Comment: @DavidK Yeah, I was asking about the conversion. For example if limits are constants, we have to ensure the smaller value appears in the lower limit and the higher value appears in the upper limit. Are there any general guidelines when this is not the case (e.g. when we have to describe more complex regions than just orthogonal regions)?

Comment: @user599310 The only general guidelines I can think of are to integrate over every part of the region so that each function value is counted exactly once in the end. (So integrating a region twice and subtracting its integral once is OK.) The iterated integrals can follow any coordinate system you want--Cartesian, polar, or something else--as long as you account for the Jacobian. And you may want to break the a region into pieces so you can use different bounds and/or coordinate systems to integrate each piece.